# Given a program which when executed spawns two concurrent processes : semaphore X : = 0 ; Is it possible for process P1 and P2 to starve?

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, deadlocks

Given below is a program which when executed spawns two concurrent processes:

```
semaphore X : = 0 ;
/* Process now forks into concurrent processes P1 & P2 */

P1                  P2
repeat forever      repeat forever
V (X) ;             P(X) ;
Compute ;          Compute ;                  
P(X) ;              V(X) ;
```

Consider the following statements about processes P1 and P2:

1. It is possible for process P1 to starve.
2. It is possible for process
       P2 to starve.

---

My attempt:

After process P1 run for one time  ;

when process P2 into critical section, process P1 can enter into critical section every time ...so it is not possible process P1 to starve.

when process P1 into critical section, process P2 can enter into critical section every time ...so it is not possible process P2 to starve.

---

Another method: Since word `possible` is used. So,

I. Case: P1 will enter its critical section once at the beginning and then only P2 keeps on entering its critical section again and again. Thus, making P1 starve.

II. Case: P1 will enter its critical section once at the beginning and then only P1 keeps on entering its critical section again and again. Thus, making P2 starve.

Now, I agree second method since `possible`. we need to find that situation so can be `possible`.

Can you explain it in a formal way?

---

I'd posted [on SO $4$ days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011404/given-a-program-which-when-executed-spawns-two-concurrent-processes-semaphore), but that is put on hold today, So, I posted on here, since CS.SE is better place for this problem.

Comment: Are the semaphores regulated by a FIFO policy? I think this is important here. Concretely, if two $P$s are tried, will the first one be woken up by the next $V$?

Comment: @chi, The problem is badly defined. This was from GATE exam.

Comment: If a FIFO policy is not assumed, your second method looks correct. P1 can get stuck on its P, while P2 loops forever. The dual is also possible: P2 gets stuck on its P while P1 loops forever. I think just showing an interleaved execution where starvation happens is enough.

Comment: Process P2 can't enter into critical section until P1 has entered at least once,so statement II is correct 

"It is **possible** for process P1 to starve."

Comment: Both process P1 and P2 may starve.

Comment: Yes I also think both may starve. But don't know if I am right. I want to know correct answer.

Comment: @SwetaShaw , both may starve.